# Debugging a calendar app on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, calendar

Here is some pastebin (don't want to put my code in the internet for ever) to build a cool calendar :

```js
var today = new Date(); // The current server date
var displayedMonth = new Date(today.getTime())
var mois = ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Aout", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Decembre"];
var jour = ["Dimanche", "Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi"];

function initialSetup(date){
 addEventListener();
 buildCalendar(date);
}

function buildCalendar(date){
 $(".currentMonth").text(mois[date.getMonth()]);
 $(".currentYear").text(date.getFullYear());
 
 if($(".itemsCalendar").length == 0){
  $(".calendar:first").append('<table class="itemsCalendar"><thead><tr></tr></thead>');  
  for(var cpt = 1; cpt <= jour.length-1;cpt++)
   $(".calendar > table > thead > tr").append('<th>'+jour[cpt].substring(0,3)+'</th>');
 
  $(".calendar > table > thead > tr").append('<th>'+jour[0].substring(0,3)+'</th>');
 }
  
 // Set the days in the calendar
 return populateCalendar(date);
}

function populateCalendar(date){
 var itsToday = null;
 var appendLocation = null;
 var sendResult = false;
 
 if($(".itemsCalendar > tbody").length == 0){
  $(".itemsCalendar").append('<tbody class="dates"></tbody>');
  appendLocation = ".dates";
 }else{
  $(".calendar").append('<tbody class="tempCalendar"></tbody>');
  appendLocation = ".tempCalendar";
  sendResult = true;
 }
 
 if(date.getMonth() == today.getMonth() && date.getYear() == today.getYear() ){ // If is it the same day than today, buid as follow
  itsToday = 'class="today"'
  // date = today;
  date.setDate(today.getDate()); // copy the date of today
 }
 
 $(appendLocation).append("<tr><td><span "+itsToday+">"+date.getDate()+"</span></td></tr>");
 var currentDay = date.getDay();
 for(var cpt = date.getDate()-1; cpt>=1;cpt--){ // For each day before
  currentDay > 0 ? currentDay-- : currentDay = 6; // Negate 1 day
  currentDay == 0 ? $(appendLocation).prepend("<tr></tr>"):null; // Add a line in needed
  $(appendLocation+"  > tr:first").prepend("<td><span>"+cpt+"</span></td>");
 }
 fillCalendar(date, currentDay, true, appendLocation);
 
 currentDay = date.getDay();
 for(var cpt = date.getDate()+1; cpt<=dayInMonth(date);cpt++){ // For each day after
  currentDay < 6 ? currentDay++ : currentDay = 0;// Increase 1 day
  currentDay == 1 ? $(appendLocation).append("<tr></tr>"):null; // Add a line if needed
  $(appendLocation+"  > tr:last").append("<td><span>"+cpt+"</span></td>");
 }
 fillCalendar(date, currentDay, false, appendLocation); 
 
 if(sendResult){
  var ret = $(".tempCalendar").html();
  $(".tempCalendar").remove();
  return ret;
 }
  
}

function dayInMonth(date){
 if(date.getMonth() == 1) if(isBissextile(date.getYear())) return 29; else return 28;
 if(date.getMonth()%2 == 0) if(date.getMonth() <= 6) return 31; else return 30; else if(date.getMonth() <= 6) return 30; else return 31;
}

function isBissextile(year){
 if(year%4 != 0) return false; else if((year%100 == 0) && (year%400 != 0)) return false; else return true;
}

function fillCalendar(date, day, isBefore, where){
 var complete;
 
 if(isBefore){
  if(day == 1) return; else complete = false;
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth()-1);
  var cpt = dayInMonth(date);
  do{
   day != 0 ? day-- : day = 6; // Negate 1 day
   $(where+"  > tr:first").prepend("<td><span class='notInTheMonth'>"+cpt+"</span></td>");
   cpt--;
   day == 1 ? complete = true : null;
  }while(!complete);
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1);
 }else{
  if(day == 0) return; else complete = false;
  var cpt = 1;
  do{
   day == 6 ? day = 0 : day++; // Increase 1 day
   $(where+"  > tr:last").append("<td><span class='notInTheMonth'>"+cpt+"</span></td>");
   cpt++;
   day == 0 ? complete = true : null;
  }while(!complete);
 }
}

function addEventListener(){
 $(".previousMonth").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  displayedMonth.setMonth(displayedMonth.getMonth()-1);
  displayedMonth.setDate(15);
  var updated = buildCalendar(displayedMonth);
  updateCalendar(updated); 
 });
 
 $(".nextMonth").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  displayedMonth.setMonth(displayedMonth.getMonth()+1);
  displayedMonth.setDate(15);
  var updated = buildCalendar(displayedMonth);
  updateCalendar(updated);
 });
 
 $(".previousYear").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  displayedMonth.setFullYear(displayedMonth.getFullYear()-1);
  displayedMonth.setDate(15);
  var updated = buildCalendar(displayedMonth);
  updateCalendar(updated);
 });
 
 $(".nextYear").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  displayedMonth.setFullYear(displayedMonth.getFullYear()+1);
  displayedMonth.setDate(15);
  var updated = buildCalendar(displayedMonth);
  updateCalendar(updated); 
 });
}

function addDayEventListener(){
 
 $(".dates").on('click', '.notInTheMonth', function() {
    var selected = parseInt($(this).text());
  if(selected > 15)
   displayedMonth.setMonth(displayedMonth.getMonth()-1);
  else 
   displayedMonth.setMonth(displayedMonth.getMonth()+1);
  
  displayedMonth.setDate(selected);
  var updated = buildCalendar(displayedMonth);
  updateCalendar(updated);
  $(".dates > tr > td > span:not(.notInTheMonth)").filter(function() {
   return parseInt($(this).text()) === selected;
  }).addClass("today")
 });
 /*$(".notInTheMonth").each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   
  });
 });*/
}

function updateCalendar(updated){
 $('.dates').animate({
  opacity: 0,
  transform: "scale(2,1)"
 },250, function(){
    updated = $(updated);
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).html(updated);
    addDayEventListener();
 $('.dates').animate({opacity: 100}, 250);
 });
 //$(".itemsCalendar > tbody").remove();
}

function colorize(colors){
 /*background: #ff3232;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff3232 0%, #ff2828 21%, #2989d8 21%, #2989d8 48%, #5aa85e 48%, #5aa85e 73%, #ffac4f 73%, #ffac4f 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff3232 0%,#ff2828 20%,#2989d8 20%,#2989d8 40%,#5aa85e 40%,#5aa85e 60%,#ffac4f 60%,#ffac4f 80%, yellow 80%,yellow 100%);
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ff3232 0%,#ff2828 21%,#2989d8 21%,#2989d8 48%,#5aa85e 48%,#5aa85e 73%,#ffac4f 73%,#ffac4f 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3232', endColorstr='#ffac4f',GradientType=1 );*/
}

initialSetup(today);
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
div,
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.planner {
  width: 66%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 280px;
}
.calendar {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333333;
  min-width: 260px;
  transition: 250ms;
}
.calendar-header {
  color: #a7a7a7;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
}
.calendar-header span,
.calendar-header a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
}
.calendar-header a:hover {
  color: #98cd60;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.calendar-header::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #9d9d9d;
  min-width: 240px;
}

tbody{
 overflow: hidden;
 max-height: 180px;
}

th {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5b5b5b;
}
td {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
td > span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
td > span:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
td > span.active {
  border: 2px solid #98cd60;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.schedule {
  margin: 0;
}
.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
  background-color: #6b6b6b;
}
.tabs .tab {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3333%;
  background-color: #6b6b6b;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333333;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0px none;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: background 0.2s;
}
.tabs .tab.active {
  background-color: #999999;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.tabs .tab.active:hover {
  background-color: #999999;
}
.tabs .tab:hover {
  background-color: #777777;
}
.tabs .tab a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.schedule-list {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 37px;
  border-left: 2px solid #cccccc;
  display: block;
}
.schedule-item {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  clear: both;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.schedule-item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  min-height: 30px;
}
.schedule-item .time {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -41px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border: 2px solid #cccccc;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.schedule-item .time span {
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
.schedule-item .description {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 305px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #fd9a4a;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.schedule-item .description .description-content {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.schedule-item .description .description-content p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #c5c5c5;
}
.schedule-item .description .description-content .contact-list {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
.schedule-item .description .description-content .contact-list .contact {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid rgba(152, 205, 96, 0.25);
  border-radius: 60px;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.schedule-item .description .description-content .contact-list .contact img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
.schedule-item .description .description-content .contact-list .contact:hover {
  border: 2px solid #98cd60;
}
.schedule-item .description .description-content .contact-list .contact.add-contact {
  color: #98cd60;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
.schedule-item .description .description-content .contact-list .contact.add-contact a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.schedule-item .description .description-content .contact-list .contact.add-contact:hover {
  background-color: rgba(152, 205, 96, 0.25);
}
.schedule-item.free .time {
  border: 2px solid #98cd60;
}
.schedule-item.free .description .description-header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #c5c5c5;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.schedule-item.free .description .description-content {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 215px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2915418/filler.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
}
footer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #c5c5c5;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
footer a {
  color: #98cd60;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.today{
    background-color: #7D7D7D;
    color: #98CD60;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width:  20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.notInTheMonth{
 background-color: #272727;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: #444444;
}

.headerWrapper{
 color: #a7a7a7;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: justify;
 line-height: 0px;
 font-size: 0px;
 padding: 10px 0px;
}

.headerWrapper::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.itemsCalendar{
 display: block;
 max-height: 225px;
}

.itemsCalendar thead, .dates tr, .tempCalendar tr{
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 table-layout: fixed;
}

.tempCalendar{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Calendrier</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div class="planner">
   <div class="calendar">
    <div class="calendar-header"> 
     <div class="headerWrapper">
      <a class="btn btn-prev previousYear">
       <i class="icon-angle-left"></i>
      </a>
      <span class="currentYear">July</span>
      <a class="btn btn-next nextYear">
       <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
      </a>
     </div>
     
     <div class="headerWrapper">
      <a class="btn btn-prev previousMonth">
       <i class="icon-angle-left"></i>
      </a>
      <span class="currentMonth"></span>
      <a class="btn btn-next nextMonth">
       <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
      </a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

[js/calendar.js](http://pastebin.com/H1KJeeAc)

[index.html](http://pastebin.com/4cgYAbkR)

[css/style.css](http://pastebin.com/XNmEbMVq)

When clicking on notInTheMonth classed elements, there will be problems (too much day in the output, more than one month passed etc...)

To trigger the first time the click event listener, you have to pass one month or one year before. After that, it will enable the click event on the notInTheMonth day (element with background dark grey and text grey, who refer to a non-in-month day.

Frequently, the problem occurs on the second or third time we click in a notInTheMonth element.

I can't correct my trouble, so can you please help me ?